# How can create Inter-Dependent SQL Jobs within SQL Agent

Tags: sql-server, sql-job

How can create Inter-Dependent SQL Jobs within SQL Agent,

***For example:*** 
Creating three SQL Jobs via script and want to schedule them inter-dependent like... 
when first Job finish then second job should start and when second job finish then third job should start and so on

**SAMPLE SCRIPT:**

```
DECLARE @MyJobName varchar(50) = 'MyJob01' 
EXEC msdb..sp_add_job @job_name =@MyJobName,@enabled=1, @start_step_id=1, @delete_level=1 --Job will delete itself after success
EXEC msdb..sp_add_jobstep @job_name=@MyJobName,@step_id=1, @step_name='STEP1',@command='SELECT * FROM TABLE1'
EXEC msdb..sp_add_jobserver @job_name =@MyJobName, @server_name = N'MySQLServer'
EXEC msdb..sp_start_job @job_name=@MyJobName

SET @MyJobName = 'MyJob02' 
EXEC msdb..sp_add_job @job_name =@MyJobName, @enabled=1,    @start_step_id=1, @delete_level=1 
EXEC msdb..sp_add_jobstep @job_name=@MyJobName,@step_id=1, @step_name='STEP1',@command='SELECT * FROM TABLE2'
EXEC msdb..sp_add_jobserver @job_name =@MyJobName, @server_name = N'MySQLServer'
EXEC msdb..sp_start_job @job_name=@MyJobName

SET @MyJobName = 'MyJob03' 
EXEC msdb..sp_add_job @job_name =@MyJobName, @enabled=1,    @start_step_id=1, @delete_level=1 
EXEC msdb..sp_add_jobstep @job_name=@MyJobName,@step_id=1, @step_name='STEP1',@command='SELECT * FROM TABLE3'
EXEC msdb..sp_add_jobserver @job_name =@MyJobName, @server_name = N'MySQLServer'
EXEC msdb..sp_start_job @job_name=@MyJobName
```

Comment: Is there any reason these can't be 3 steps within the same job?

Comment: Yes need to track each step individually and status will be showing to requester timely. therefore cannot add multi steps in one job,  thx

Comment: You can monitor the progress of each step individually.  Have a look at the contents of `msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory`

Answer (score 0):

A job step can execute a SQL Server Agent job. So you can create another job that executes MyJob01, then MyJob02, then MyJob03. See [sp_start_job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-start-job-transact-sql). Something like

```
EXEC dbo.sp_start_job N'MyJob01' ;  
EXEC dbo.sp_start_job N'MyJob02' ;  
EXEC dbo.sp_start_job N'MyJob03' ;
```

Comment: @Haseeb: Well, you have to decide first whether your jobs will run under script control or under schedule control. But one SQL Server Agent job can enable/disable or schedule other SQL Server Agent jobs. One job can even create other jobs. But that doesn't sound like a good idea to me.

Comment: yes i just realized your answer, i need to control it using logics but yes you are right, let me work on your solution thx